# Join 2 Tables and display everything

Tags: sql, mysql, ms-access

I have 2 simple tables:

### table a:

```
id | txt
---+----
0  | aaa
1  | bbb
2  | ccc
```

### table b:

```
id | tel
---+----
0  | 000
2  | 111
```

I am trying to join 2 tables like this:

```
SELECT a.*,b.* 
  FROM a,b 
 WHERE a.id=b.id
```

It works, **but**, if there is no entry in the "b" table it wont show anything.

what the sql shows is something like this:

```
id | txt | tel
---+-----+----
0  | aaa | 000
2  | ccc | 111
```

I also want to list the "empty" row a.id=1:

```
id | txt | tel
---+-----+-----
1  | bbb | NULL
```

Any ideas? Thanks!
(SQL is for MS Access / oledb)

Comment: @Asaph: If you're going to pretty it up, add some lights & tinsle. eh? =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a [left outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Outer_joins) (or a full outer join, if you want rows in which there is no entry in the `a` table also).

```
SELECT a.*,b.* FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.id=b.id
```

Depending the system, the syntax `LEFT JOIN` may work as well.

Answer (score 2):

In MSAccess query designer, right click on the relationship connection between the two tables, and edit its properties. Modify it to 'show all records from table a'.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
SELECT a.*,b.* 
  FROM a, b 
 WHERE a.id = b.id
```

...is ANSI-89 inner join syntax, and I highly recommend using ANSI-92 syntax instead:

```
SELECT a.*,
       b.*
  FROM TABLE_A a
  JOIN TABLE_B b ON b.id = a.id
```

...mostly because ANSI-88 syntax for left joining to tables wasn't consistently implemented on various databases.  This will return the results you expect:

```
   SELECT a.id,
          a.txt,
          b.tel
     FROM TABLE_A a
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B b ON b.id = a.id
```

A LEFT JOIN means you'll get all the records from TABLE_A in this example, and when there is a matching record (based on the `ON` criteria) in TABLE_B, the value will be displayed.  Otherwise, the TABLE_B column references will return NULL values.

For more information on JOINs, see [this page for a great pictorial demonstration of what each one represents and how they compare](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/).

Comment: Wouldn't that be ANSI-86 or ANSI-89? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL doesn't show that any ANSI-88 exists.